# YouTube LiveStream Api - How to Unlist live replay once stream ends, using YouTube Api?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

Cannot find to make this in their [LiveBroadcasts: insert documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert)

Any idea which parameter need add to body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [YouTube Live Streaming API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started) [LiveBroadcasts: insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert) endpoint doesn't seem to support this feature. Maybe you could manually after your livestream proceed with [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Videos: update](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update) endpoint by changing the privacy status thanks to [`snippet.privacyStatus`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.privacyStatus). If you are interested in detecting automatically when your livestream ended, then [this section of the YouTube Live Streaming API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/life-of-a-broadcast#step_61_poll_the_data_api_for_the_videos_status) may interest you.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer! I also come to conclusion it's the only way to do this. If I schedule finish of the Broadcast at certain time, best is to set changing privacy status to same time or a bit earlier. Will try to learn how auto detect, but seems it's a bit hard for me as a beginner in this.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74070062/7123660) is your question, concerning updating [`snippet.privacyStatus`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.privacyStatus) video per video, following your initial question.