# How to update multiple videos/LiveBroadcasts one by one (using list of their ID's), using YouTube API in Python?

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I know that it's impossible to bulk update videos, using YouTube API.

How can I update several videos/LiveBroadcasts in Python by their ID?

I have working script sample, but it applies only on 1st video from list:

```
###Getting Credentials
***
###GET ID's list OF ALL BROADCASTS  
def main():
    youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
    request = youtube.liveBroadcasts().list(
        part="contentDetails",
        broadcastStatus="all",
        broadcastType="all",
        maxResults=100
        )
    response = request.execute()
    for item in response["items"]:
        response_id=item["id"]
        print(response_id)
###Make all ID of Broadcasts UNLISTED
    request = youtube.liveBroadcasts().update(
            part="status",
            body={
              "id": "{}".format(response_id), #applies only on 1st video ID, first line from "response_id"
              "status": {
                "privacyStatus": "unlisted"
              }
            }
        )
    response = request.execute()
    print(response)    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`print(response_id)` is:

```
1st video ID
2nd video ID
3rd video ID
etc
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an incorrect indentation. You are looking for executing `youtube.liveBroadcasts().update` function at each iteration in the loop `for item in response["items"]:` so you should have:

```
    for item in response["items"]:
        response_id=item["id"]
        print(response_id)
        ###Make all ID of Broadcasts UNLISTED
        request = youtube.liveBroadcasts().update(
            part="status",
            body={
              "id": "{}".format(response_id), #applies only on 1st video ID, first line from "response_id"
              "status": {
                "privacyStatus": "unlisted"
              }
            }
        )
        response = request.execute()
        print(response)
```

Instead of:

```
    for item in response["items"]:
        response_id=item["id"]
        print(response_id)
###Make all ID of Broadcasts UNLISTED
    request = youtube.liveBroadcasts().update(
            part="status",
            body={
              "id": "{}".format(response_id), #applies only on 1st video ID, first line from "response_id"
              "status": {
                "privacyStatus": "unlisted"
              }
            }
        )
    response = request.execute()
    print(response)
```

This is the reason why you have as output the following, as in Python when using a variable assigned in a loop, the last assignment is kept when quitting the loop scope (that's why only the latest video of your list got updated successfully):

```
1st video ID
2nd video ID
3rd video ID
etc
response
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! So simple solution, yes my mistake was about indentation, starting with `request = youtube.liveBroadcasts().update` and till `response = request.execute()` should be under `for...` . I am very beginner to this, so just put it next to other script